# Flask - custom decorator breaks the routing

Tags: python, json, decorator, flask

I have the following Flask routes and a custom helper:

```
from spots import app, db
from flask import Response
import simplejson as json


def json_response(action_func):
    def create_json_response(*args, **kwargs):
        ret = action_func(*args, **kwargs)
        code = 200
        if len(ret) == 2:
            code = ret[0]
            resp = ret[1]
        else:
            resp = ret[0]
        return Response(
            response=json.dumps(resp, indent=4),
            status=code,
            content_type='application/json'
        )

    return create_json_response


@app.route('/test')
@json_response
def test():
    return 400, dict(result="Test success")


@app.route('/')
@json_response
def home():
    return 200, dict(result="Home success")
```

I would expect a GET request to /test to return something like `{"result":"Test success"}` but that is not the case. Instead, any request seems to match the last route, i.e. `home`. Why?

I wonder if this is caused by some lack of insulation between the different calls to `json_response`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `code = ret[0]; resp = ret[1]` would be neater as `code, resp = ret`, and `resp = ret[0]` as `resp, = ret` (though I think it's still not how you'd want to use it, your function would need to `return {},` rather than `return {}`). Beyond that, it looks correct to me.

Comment: Just a guess - the function's signature is broken, you may want to try [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: I want to see the answer to this

Comment: @VidulPetrov your solution worked - using functools.wraps fixed the issue.

Comment: @VidulPetrov put your suggestion/answer into the answer area so you get credit

Comment: Just a note - Flask provides a [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#returning-json) function that will do what your custom decorator does but in the return statement (you would simply replace `dict` with `jsonify`).

Comment: @SeanVieira I know but I might be building something else around it - but thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 14):

As Видул Петров said the solution is to use [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps):

```
import functools
def json_response(action_func):
    @functools.wraps(action_func)
    def create_json_response(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
return create_json_response
```

The reason is that Flask’s routing system maps URLs to "endpoints", and then endpoints to view functions. The endpoint defaults to the `__name__` attribute of the view function. In this case the decorated function was passed to `app.route` so the endpoint was `create_json_response` for both rules and the last view defined for that endpoint was used in both cases.

functools.wraps takes the `__name__` (and other attributes) from the original function and fixes this. It is always a good idea to use it in decorated wrappers.

Comment: flask has document about this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/viewdecorators/